# Nginx: Speeding up Image Upload?

Tags: python, image, nginx

My python application sits behind an Nginx instance. When I upload an image, which is one of the purpose of my app, I notice that nginx first saves the image in filesystem (used 'watch ls -l /tmp') and then hands it over to the app. Can I configure Nginx to work in-memory with image POST? My intent is to avoid touching the slow filesystem (the server runs on an embedded device).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set the `proxy_max_temp_file_size` to zero, or some other reasonably small value.  Another option (which might be a better choice) is to set the `proxy_temp_path` to faster storage so that nginx can do a slightly better job of insulating the application from buggy or malicious hosts.

Comment: Tried proxy_max_temp_file_size in the server section but that didn't work. Also tried setting proxy_buffering to off. Am I missing something basic?

Comment: proxy_buffering is for responses, so it's no surprise that didn't help.

Comment: Only proxy_max_temp_file_size also didn't work. You know what I may be missing?